# Doing Live/Dynamic changes in Swing

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, windowbuilder

I am making a game having squares in it (a grid of panels) and when the game ends there is an algorithm that changes the color of the panels one by one in a "live" fashion where the user watches the squares change color slowly. I try something like:

```
Thread.sleep(1000);      

grid.getComponent(boxNumber).setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

Thread.sleep(1000); 

grid.getComponent(boxNumber).setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
```

Although the color of a box changes to Yellow, it does not change to Orange afterwards. Anyone have any ideas? Hope I was able to be clear.

Comment: Have you tried calling `invalidate`?

Comment: Nope, dont know much about it. I am kinda new to Swing. Will give it a try. Thanks.
EDIT:I just took a look and I am not sure how that is going to help me =/

Comment: There in no need to call invalidate(). Swing components will repaint themselves automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) to understand why you should not be using the sleep() method.

One solution is to use a SwingWorker, then you can 'publish' the color of the component so it can be updated properly on the EDT and you can invoke the sleep() method in the worker as well.

Answer (score 1):

These need to happen on the Swing event thread. call set background via:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    grid.getComponent(boxNumber).setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
  }
});
```

Note, your `Thread.sleep()` should **not** be in the event thread (or directly from within a Swing event listener (ActionListener, WindowListener, etc).

It would also be prudent to look the [Swing Timing Framework](http://java.net/projects/timingframework/) which is specifically for things like this.

Answer (score 1):

-Generally its not a good idea to do `Thread.sleep(1000);` in the EDT.  You should try using [Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).
-You also need to call `revalidate()/validate() and repaint()` afterward.

So maybe something like this:

```
Timer yellowTimer = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             jtp.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            //call revalidate()/validate() and repaint() afterward
             jtp.revalidate();
             jtp.repaint();
        }
    });
yellowTimer.setRepeats(false);

Timer orangeTimer = new Timer(2000,new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             jtp.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
             //call revalidate()/validate() and repaint() afterward
             jtp.revalidate();
             jtp.repaint();
        }
    });
orangeTimer.setRepeats(false);

yellowTimer.start();
orangeTimer.start();
```

Comment: +1 Timer is a potential solution (but not the best since now the logic is spread across two classes). -1, revalidate() is not required since the size of the component doesn't change and repaint() is not required as Swing components are smart enough to repaint themselves.